# React/Flask 'request.cookies.get' Returns None

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, cookies

I'm setting a cookie when the user logs in

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def user_login():
 login=request.get_json()
 database_response, user = database.find_user(login['loginEmail'], login['loginPassword])
 if database_response and user:
  user_id_from_db = str(user['user_id'])
  user_cookie = make_response(database_response, user)
  user_cookie.set_cookie('user_id', user_id_from_db)
  return user_cookie
 else:
  return database_response
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve user_cookie in my login_required decorator and just print it for now:

```
def login_required(func):
 @wraps(func)
 def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
  requested_cookie = request.cookies.get('user_id')
  print(requested_cookie) #shows up as None
  return func(*args, **kwargs)
 return wrapper
```

I'm using this decorator on different route functions to verify the user by the cookie, but even just trying to print it, it shows None.
Even if I request the cookie in one of those functions I'm decorating, it shows None.
I've handled all the CORS errors I received so far. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you check whether the cookie actually exists on the browser after login is done? I think you are having issues with the expiry of the cookie due to which it's being set, but also expiring immediately after that

Comment: Also, could you take a dump (print) of the request object and see the available keys in it?

Comment: @SaiprasadBalasubramanian Thanks for your reply.
The cookie does show up on the browser when the user logs in. I also added an expiry date 90 days from now. 
But the login_required request.cookies.get still shows None. I printed the request object, and it shows, <Request 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/setpassword' [POST]>
(I use the login_required on the set password route)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out on my front end doing the fetch call, I had:

```
withCredentials: true
```

instead of

```
credentials: 'include'
```

I am able to grab the cookies now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on this line in the decorator code `requested_cookie = request.cookie.get('user_id')`

It should be `request.cookies`, you are missing an **s** in cookies.

So basically, `request.cookies` is a dict of all the cookies available in the request context.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just checked my original code, it does have the 's' in request.cookies.get. I'll edit this to have the right syntax.
What I'm finding out is that this is a common problem when people are using a javascript framework with flask. Since it's two different domains running at the same time, cookies will not work properly. But I don't know what I could use for it to run on the same domain. If anyone has info on this, that would be greatly appreciated